# Cannot find managedObjectModel

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

This piece of code is crashing my application

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {

    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.

    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("appTest", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()
```

Specifically at the `let modelURL =` assignment (I placed breakpoints)

With:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

So I figure that could either mean

1- it can't find the appTest.momd file because the name changed or

2- it just hasn't been created.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure you have the `appTest.momd` file included in your project?

Comment: And, do tell, what is the error message?

Comment: @Alexander how do I check that ?

Comment: @JodyHagins I just edited my question with the error being raised

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a spelling error. Most likely, your model is called "AppTest" rather than "appTest".

You should be able to locate the model by selecting the search box at the bottom of your project navigator and starting to type the name of the file. It should end in `.xcdatamodeld`.

If it is missing, add a new file of type "Data Model" to the project and make sure the names match.